# Email does not display in HTML format

Tags: php, email

I am using the following code:

```
$useremail="xxx@gmail.com";
$admin_email="yyy@gmail.com";
$sub="some meassage";
$content=<design with tables>.................;

$reval=mail($useremail,$sub,$content,'From:'. $admin_email));
```

The code sends the email correctly, but it displays in text format not HTML format which is what I want.

I am using Content-type:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'. $admin_email. "\r\n";
$reval=mail($useremail,$sub,$content,$headers);
```

In this method the email is not delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

By :

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

**Full code example :**

```
$useremail="xxx@gmail.com";
$admin_email="yyy@gmail.com";
$sub="some meassage";
$content = "Good morning,<br />
<strong>This is an HTML msg sent by php mail.</strong><br />
Thanks :)";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"";
$headers .= 'From:'. $admin_email. "\r\n";

$reval=mail($useremail,$sub,$content,$headers);

if($reval)
{
    echo "mail sent";
}
else
{
    echo "error.";
}
```

it's work for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But, this method is also not delivered, but both the methods the $reval values is true.